# Launch program with python on a specific core

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, cpu-cores

Is there any way to launch a program by its API using Python and run it on a specified core?

I need to launch a CPU-expensive application about 5 times and run it on different cores to save time.

I'm using windows.

Comment: You should probably be using the actual `multiprocessing` module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process can set its own affinity, here is what I do (you can change the mask, or make it a parameter, to identify which cores you want to use.)

```
import win32api, win32con, win32process

def setaffinity():
    pid  = win32api.GetCurrentProcessId()
    mask = 128 # core 7
    handle = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, True, pid)
    win32process.SetProcessAffinityMask(handle, mask)
```

Comment: @Gall  Thanks for the edit - is there a tutorial on formatting I can read up on?

Comment: There is the [Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) which contains very useful information. In addition, you can select multiple lines and hit Ctrl+k to format a code block in an easy way.